# If a piston has a larger upper surface area than lower surface area experience a force downwards even if that piston is ventilated?

Tags: fluid-mechanics, pressure, pressure-vessel

Here I have a system where there is 18 bar of Nitrogen in a valve with a piston. The pressurized nitrogen is below the piston, above the piston, and also in the ventilation bore in the piston. Nitrogen can move freely between these three volumes.

Since the upper surface area of the piston is greater than the lower surface area of the piston, I would expect a difference in "pneumatic force" between the top and bottom of the piston, which would drive the piston downwards (as the upwards pneumatic force is lower than the downwards pneumatic force).

However the small ventilation bore in the piston makes me feel unsure. I can't think of a reason why this ventilation bore would prevent the piston from functioning this way, as pressure should still act on every surface equally, right?

So my question is: will the piston experience a net downwards force proportional to the difference in areas as a result of the difference in surface areas from the top of the piston to the bottom (even if the piston is ventilated)?
[image: Piston with ventilation bore and different surface areas]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, even if the ventilation bore has an oval or kidney shape or is significantly larger. The difference between the top and bottom areas times approximately 17 bars (18 bars-1 atm) will be the net force acting on the piston.

Despite its size or shape, the 18 bars of pressure acting on the ventilation bore's walls cancel each other out. The remaining forces are the top and bottom forces!

Comment: That's what I figured, thanks for your reply!